# Neyman-Pearson lemma for the sample of size one

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable on $[0, 1]$ with a density function
$$f(\theta |x ) = \frac{x^{\theta}}{\theta + 1}$$

Let's take a sample that consists on the only one element from the given distribution, say $x_{1}$ and test the following hypothesis:

$$H_{0}: \theta = 0 \ \ \ \  \text{vs. } \ \ \ H_{1}: \theta = 1$$

Neyman - Pearson lemma gives

$$\lambda(x) = \frac{L(\theta = 0 | x)}{L(\theta = 1 | x)} = \frac{2}{x}$$

Thus, the rejection regions consists of presicely those $x$ that satsify $\frac{2}{x} \leq a$.

In order to find $a$, we calculate
$$\mathbb{P}(\lambda(x) \leq a | H_{0}) = \mathbb{P}(x \geq \frac{2}{a} | H_{0}) = \int_{\frac{2}{a}}^{1} {1_{[0, 1]} dx} = 1 - \frac{2}{a}$$

Thus  $\frac{2}{a} = 1 - \alpha$ and we reject the hypothesis if $x \leq 1 - \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the significance level.

As for me that sounds quite counter-intuitive, since for the large values of $\alpha$ we have the critical value concentrated near the end on an interval, which i strongly doubt. Am i missing something crucial here?

Comment: Your $f$ is not a pdf in the first place; $f(x\mid\theta)=(\theta+1)x^{\theta}\mathbf1_{[0,1]}(x)$ for $\theta>-1$ makes more sense.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Ouh, indeed, thanks. In fact, this is a distribution in case $\theta = 0$, but in this case the problem boils down to somewhat very strange and trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is nothing wrong with that. For example, let $\alpha = 0.99$. It means that we allow large probability of type 1 error (almost don't care about it) and we may end up with large critical region. Actually, corresponding critical region is
$$
x\geq 1-\alpha = 0.01,
$$ and almost any value of $x$ leads to rejection of $H_0$ as expected. As a result, we get a very powerful test at the expense of significance level.